# Create distance intervals along a Route + Cross Section

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, linear-referencing, route

I believe I've done this before but years ago.

My goal is to make a X-Section of a line using a DEM. I want to create a Route (from a Polyline), give this route 1k intervals, and then "drape" it to my DEM. I then would like to create a cross section.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

I can see in 3D analyst I can digitise the line and create to create the x section but I am wanting to use the Route so I can show intervals along the line etc.

So far all I've done is create the route, I'm not sure how to break the line up into 1k intervals?

Comment: When you say "break the line up into 1k intervals" do you mean to split the line into multiple lines or just to display markers at 1k intervals using point events along your route using linear referencing?

Comment: Sorry just to display markers at 1k intervals